# Laravel - Storing a file then saving its name and id in database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, eloquent

So I have a form that chooses a file and uploads it to /storage/app/attachments.

that part of the program works fine. The file uploads and stores. But I then receive an error:

(1/1) ErrorException 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::$id

I assume the program is getting stuck on the updating the database with the uploaded files id. But I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Laravel says it is on my upload controller on line 33. (see below)

```
    class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadForm()
    {
        return view('upload_form');
    }

    public function uploadSubmit(UploadRequest $request)
    {
        $attachment = Attachment::create($request->all());
        foreach ($request->attachments as $attachment) {
            $filename = $attachment->store('attachments');
            AttachmentsFile::create([
                'attachment_id' => $attachment->id,
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);
        }
        return 'Upload successful!';
    }
```

UploadRequest controller

```
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required'
        ];
        $attachments = count($this->input('attachments'));
        foreach(range(0, $attachments) as $index) {
            $rules['attachments.' . $index] = 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,doc,docm,docxm,pdf,xml,zip,rar|max:20000';
        }

        return $rules;

    }
}
```

Upload view

```
 <div class="col-md-4"></div>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="media-list well" id="content-wells">


    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif

        <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            Product name:
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <br /><br />
            Product photos (can attach more than one):
            <br />
            <input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple />
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
        <!--http://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/-->
  </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you dd($attachment) ?

Comment: paste bin of the dd results: https://pastebin.com/LW0PncEF

Comment: `$attachment = Attachment::create($request->all());` this query was successful ? check DB.

Comment: I'm not sure how that fits into my program? Because  trying to implement it gives me an sql error